# why clock_gettime is async signal safe

Tags: c, multithreading

From the function definition:

```
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec * tp);
```

this function is expecting a pointer of `timespec` struct. I was wondering why this async signal safe if we passed the same global variable struct `timespec`? E.g The main program is call `clock_gettime` while a signal interrupt happens and call `clock_gettime` again, both of them passing a global `timespec` struct pointer. Are they interfering each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing won't be *async signal safe*. But it's your own code that's unsafe, not the function itself. Using a "global" inside and outside a signal handler is *never* safe if it isn't atomic. There's only one type guaranteed to be atomic wrt signal handlers: `sig_atomic_t`. Don't forget to declare it `volatile` as well.

`clock_gettime()` **is** *async signal safe*, but that doesn't guard you from your own mistakes.